# Office 2016 package will not install

Tags: ms-office, install

I'm trying to install Office 2016 and it appears as though Installer will not run/install the .pkg file. When you double click on the package itself it instantly exits, leaving behind these errors:

`CoreServicesUIAgent[323]: Error -60005 creating authorization`

and

`com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000011.Installer[859]) Service exited due to signal: Broken pipe: 13`

I've tried repairing disk permissions and rebooting (multiple times) as well as re-downloading the package from MSFT, no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your account an Administrator or Standard account? If Standard, try using an Administrator account to install the package.

Comment: It's an Administrator account.

Comment: Then in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General` tab authenticate by clicking the lock icon in the lower left, then select the `Anywhere` radio button in the `Allow apps downloaded from:` section & try to open the .pkg file again.

Comment: Good idea, but that didn't change anything either :(

Comment: Q: What version of OS X is on your Mac/Mac specs? This [page](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-system-requirements) lists the OS requirements. It looks like 10.10 is the minimum spec for OS X. Next troubleshooting step: create a new Administrator account & download/install the .pkg again. If you've installed the Office '16 Preview, you probably want to uninstall it.

Comment: 10.10.5 - don't have the preview installed, but do have Office 2011 installed.

Comment: I am also having this exact same issue. I tried repairing disk permissions and installing in safe mode. Nothing happens. Frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

The (odd) answer to this question turned out to be a corrupted installer that came from our implementation of O365. When provided with a different installer it worked fine.